# PHP PDO Read SQLLite DB From Memory (variable)

Tags: php, sqlite, memory, pdo

Here is the scenario

client app, prepare data, make SQLite db, compress it (zip), encode the zip file and send to server.

Now, at server end, I decode the zip file, then de-compress it, store the SQLite db data to a variable like $strLiteData.

now I need to use that variable/data using PDO, but it seems, PDO only support real file or "memory".

So, only option I have to save the SQLite db data to file first, then load that file. and to maintain uniqueness i have to create unique folder, files etc for that.

Isn't there any way to read directly form the variable using PDO?

Comment: You can do it in C with the right extension module, but most languages sqlite bindings don't provide that kind of power or flexibility. Easier to just save the data as a file and open it the normal way.

Comment: With all that implementation overhead, having to have a proper file/unique filenames does seem somewhat negligible.

Answer (score 0):

On most machines, temporary files are created in-memory, so we can essentially copying the database from one place in the memory to another, which is what loading a database directly from a variable would do anyway.

> and to maintain uniqueness i have to create unique folder, files etc for that.

Let PHP handle uniqueness with `tmpfile()`. Although the file is generally visible by all users (on Linux, located in `/tmp` by default), the value is only accessible to the current user, and the filename is always something nondescript like `php8c1vRQ`.

Here is an example that stores the result back to $strLiteData when you are done running queries:

```php
$strLiteData = /* from your zip file */

$dbFile = tmpfile();
$dbPath = stream_get_meta_data($dbFile)['uri'];

fwrite($dbFile, $strLiteData);

$pdo = new PDO('sqlite:' . $dbPath);

/*
 * do your PDO stuff here
 */

$strLiteData = file_get_contents($dbPath);
```

PHP will automatically remove the temporary file when the script ends.

Comment: sir, you use fwrite to store file data, what if i use file_put_contents? hope will do the same...

Comment: @Zakir_SZH Yes, it will do the same thing. The reason I used `fwrite()` is that it comes out to be fewer characters than if using `file_put_contents()`, but either one is fine. Just make sure you don't `fclose()` the `$dbFile` resource until you are done with your PDO stuff and have read the data back into `$strLiteData`, because `fclose()` will remove the temporary file.